# Pandas groupby: Count the number of occurrences within a time range for each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, date-difference, rolling-sum

I have a dataframe:

```
ID  DATE       WIN
A   2015/6/5   Yes
A   2015/6/7   Yes
A   2015/6/7   Yes
A   2015/6/7   Yes
B   2015/6/8   No
B   2015/8/7   Yes
C   2015/5/15  Yes
C   2015/5/30  No
C   2015/7/30  No
C   2015/8/03  Yes
```

I want to add a column that counts the number of wins for each `ID` within the past 1 month, so the result will look like:

```
ID  DATE       WIN  NumOfDaysSinceLastWin NumOfWinsInThePast30days
A   2015/6/5   Yes           0               0       
A   2015/6/7   Yes           2               1 
A   2015/6/7   Yes           2               1 or (A 2015/6/7 Yes 0 2)
A   2015/6/8   No            1               3 
B   2015/8/7   No            0               0
B   2015/8/7   Yes           0               0
C   2015/5/15  Yes           0               0
C   2015/5/30  No            15              1
C   2015/7/30  No            76              0
C   2015/8/03  Yes           80              0
```

How can I use `groupby` function and `timegrouper` to get this?

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631139/pandas-rolling-computations-on-sliding-windows-unevenly-spaced

Comment: And `rolling_sum` function - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_sum.html

Comment: For the third win by `A`, shouldn't that be 0 for `NumOfDaysSinceLastWin`? That date is the same as the previous win. Either that, the title of the column should be `NumOfDaysSinceFirstWin`, right?

Comment: @dawg There are two interpretations. If two games happened on the same day at the same time, then number of days since last win would be 2. If the second win happened one hour ahead of the third win, then number of days since last win for the third row would be 0,which is the result I put in the brackets. Either interpretation works. It should be the number of days since the previous win, not the first win.

Answer (score 1):

Input data **has to be sorted** in each group by DATE, in this data is it OK.
Input data cannot mapped situation very well, so next 4 rows will be added.

Column `WIN1` is created from `WIN` - values `1` for `'Yes'` and `0` for `'No'`. I need it for both output columns.

```
df['WIN1'] = df['WIN'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else 0)
```

### Column `NumOfDaysSinceLastWin`

Firstly column `cumsum` (cumulative sum) is created.

```
df['cumsum'] = df['WIN1'].cumsum()
```

If all `WIN` are `'Yes'`, it is easy. Data will be grouped and difference between date and previous date(-1) value is in columns `diffs`.

```
#df['diffs'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'cumsum'])['DATE'].apply(lambda d: (d-d.shift()).fillna(0))
```

But situation is complicated, because value `'No'` of column `WIN`. So if value is `'Yes'`, you need difference with **previous** `'Yes'`, if `'No'` need difference  with **last previous** `'WIN'`. Difference can be counted many ways, but there is chosen by subtracting two columns - `DATE` and column `date1`.

**Column `date1`**
Rows has to be grouped special way - values `'No'` and last previous `'Yes'`. It is possible by cumulative sum in column `cumsum`. 
Then minimal value of this group is value of `'Yes'` column and then this value is repeating to rows with `'No'` values. 
Column `count` is special - no repeating values of `cumsum` column are `1`. Repeating ones are incremented in groups.

```
df['min'] = df.groupby(['ID','cumsum'])['DATE'].transform('min')
df['count'] = df.groupby(['cumsum'])['cumsum'].transform('count')
```

Dates of values `'YES'` in previous rows are necessary for difference. Dataframe `df1` filtered only values `'Yes'` of df and then then grouped it by column `ID`. Indices are unchanged, so output can be mapped to new column of dataframe `df`.

```
df1 = df[~df['WIN'].isin(['No'])]
df['date1'] = df1.groupby(['ID'])['DATE'].apply(lambda d: d.shift()) 
print df

   ID       DATE  WIN  WIN1  cumsum        min  count      date1
0   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       1 2015-06-05      1        NaT
1   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       2 2015-06-05      1 2015-06-05
2   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       3 2015-06-07      1 2015-06-05
3   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       4 2015-06-07      1 2015-06-07
4   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       5 2015-06-07      4 2015-06-07
5   A 2015-06-08   No     0       5 2015-06-07      4        NaT
6   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07      4        NaT
7   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07      4        NaT
8   B 2015-08-07  Yes     1       6 2015-08-07      1        NaT
9   C 2015-05-15  Yes     1       7 2015-05-15      3        NaT
10  C 2015-05-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15      3        NaT
11  C 2015-07-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15      3        NaT
12  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       8 2015-08-03      1 2015-05-15
13  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       9 2015-08-03      1 2015-08-03
```

Then date columns `min` (values `'No'` and last previous `'Yes'`) and column `date1` (other values `'Yes'`) can be join by columns `count`.
New condition was added - values of column `date1` will be null - (`NaT`), because these values will be overwritten by column `min`.

```
df.loc[(df['count'] > 1) & (df['date1'].isnull()), 'date1'] = df['min']
print df

   ID       DATE  WIN  WIN1  cumsum        min  count      date1
0   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       1 2015-06-05      1 2015-06-05
1   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       2 2015-06-05      1 2015-06-05
2   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       3 2015-06-07      1 2015-06-05
3   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       4 2015-06-07      1 2015-06-07
4   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       5 2015-06-07      4 2015-06-07
5   A 2015-06-08   No     0       5 2015-06-07      4 2015-06-07
6   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07      4 2015-06-07
7   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07      4 2015-06-07
8   B 2015-08-07  Yes     1       6 2015-08-07      1 2015-08-07
9   C 2015-05-15  Yes     1       7 2015-05-15      3 2015-05-15
10  C 2015-05-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15      3 2015-05-15
11  C 2015-07-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15      3 2015-05-15
12  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       8 2015-08-03      1 2015-05-15
13  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       9 2015-08-03      1 2015-08-03
```

**Repeating datetimes - subsolution**
Sorry, if this is made this complicated way, maybe someone find better one.
My solution is find repeating values, fill them by last previous `'Yes'` and added to column `date1` for difference.
These values are identified in column `count`. Other (values `1`) are reset to `NaN`. Then values from `date1` are copied to `date2` by column `count`.

```
df['count'] = df1.groupby(['ID', 'DATE', 'WIN1'])['WIN1'].transform('count')
df.loc[df['count'] == 1 , 'count'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['count'].notnull() , 'date2'] = df['date1']
print df    

   ID       DATE  WIN  WIN1  cumsum        min  count      date1      date2
0   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       1 2015-06-05      2 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
1   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       2 2015-06-05      2 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
2   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       3 2015-06-07      3 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
3   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       4 2015-06-07      3 2015-06-07 2015-06-07
4   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       5 2015-06-07      3 2015-06-07 2015-06-07
5   A 2015-06-08   No     0       5 2015-06-07    NaN 2015-06-07        NaT
6   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07    NaN 2015-06-07        NaT
7   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07    NaN 2015-06-07        NaT
8   B 2015-08-07  Yes     1       6 2015-08-07    NaN 2015-08-07        NaT
9   C 2015-05-15  Yes     1       7 2015-05-15    NaN 2015-05-15        NaT
10  C 2015-05-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15    NaN 2015-05-15        NaT
11  C 2015-07-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15    NaN 2015-05-15        NaT
12  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       8 2015-08-03      2 2015-05-15 2015-05-15
13  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       9 2015-08-03      2 2015-08-03 2015-08-03
```

Then this values are repeated by group's minimal value and added to `date1` column.

```
def repeat_value(grp):
    grp['date2'] = grp['date2'].min()
    return grp

df = df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE']).apply(repeat_value)
df.loc[df1['date2'].notnull() , 'date1'] = df['date2']
print df

   ID       DATE  WIN  WIN1  cumsum        min  count      date1      date2
0   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       1 2015-06-05      2 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
1   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1       2 2015-06-05      2 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
2   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       3 2015-06-07      3 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
3   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       4 2015-06-07      3 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
4   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1       5 2015-06-07      3 2015-06-05 2015-06-05
5   A 2015-06-08   No     0       5 2015-06-07    NaN 2015-06-07        NaT
6   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07    NaN 2015-06-07        NaT
7   B 2015-06-07   No     0       5 2015-06-07    NaN 2015-06-07        NaT
8   B 2015-08-07  Yes     1       6 2015-08-07    NaN 2015-08-07        NaT
9   C 2015-05-15  Yes     1       7 2015-05-15    NaN 2015-05-15        NaT
10  C 2015-05-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15    NaN 2015-05-15        NaT
11  C 2015-07-30   No     0       7 2015-05-15    NaN 2015-05-15        NaT
12  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       8 2015-08-03      2 2015-05-15 2015-05-15
13  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1       9 2015-08-03      2 2015-05-15 2015-05-15
```

Column `NumOfDaysSinceLastWin` is filled by difference of col `date1` and `DATE`. Datatype is `Timedelta`, so it will be converted to integer. Finally unnecessary columns will be deleted.
(Only columns `WIN1` and `count` is necessary for next output column, so it isn't deleted.)

```
df['NumOfDaysSinceLastWin'] = ((df['DATE'] - df['date1']).fillna(0)).astype('timedelta64[D]')
df = df.drop(['cumsum','min', 'date1'], axis=1 )
print df
   ID       DATE  WIN  WIN1  count  NumOfDaysSinceLastWin
0   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1      2                      0
1   A 2015-06-05  Yes     1      2                      0
2   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1      3                      2
3   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1      3                      2
4   A 2015-06-07  Yes     1      3                      2
5   A 2015-06-08   No     0    NaN                      1
6   B 2015-06-07   No     0    NaN                      0
7   B 2015-06-07   No     0    NaN                      0
8   B 2015-08-07  Yes     1    NaN                      0
9   C 2015-05-15  Yes     1    NaN                      0
10  C 2015-05-30   No     0    NaN                     15
11  C 2015-07-30   No     0    NaN                     76
12  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1      2                     80
13  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1      2                     80
```

### Column `NumOfWinsInThePast30days`

Rolling sum is your friend. Column `yes` (necessary for resampling) is mapped by `1` for `'Yes'` and `NaN` for `'No'`.

```
df['yes'] = df['WIN'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else np.nan)
```

Dataframe `df2` is copy of `df` and columns `DATE` is set to index (for resampling). Unnecessary columns will be deleted.

```
df2 = df.set_index('DATE')
df2 = df2.drop(['NumOfDaysSinceLastWin','WIN', 'WIN1'], axis=1)
```

Then `df2` will be resampling by days, if row is `'Yes'` value is `1`, if `'No'` is `0`. (Better see bellow as explain.)

```
df2 = df2.groupby('ID').resample("D", how='count')
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

Dataframe `df2` will be grouped by `ID` and function `rolling_sum` is using for these groups.

```
df2['rollsum'] = df2.groupby('ID')['yes'].transform(pd.rolling_sum, window=30, min_periods=1)
```

For better understanding all rows of `df2` will be displayed.

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999, 'display.max_columns', 5):
    print df2

    ID       DATE  yes  rollsum
0    A 2015-06-05    2        2
1    A 2015-06-06    0        2
2    A 2015-06-07    3        5
3    A 2015-06-08    0        5
4    B 2015-06-07    0        0
5    B 2015-06-08    0        0
6    B 2015-06-09    0        0
7    B 2015-06-10    0        0
8    B 2015-06-11    0        0
9    B 2015-06-12    0        0
10   B 2015-06-13    0        0
11   B 2015-06-14    0        0
12   B 2015-06-15    0        0
13   B 2015-06-16    0        0
14   B 2015-06-17    0        0
15   B 2015-06-18    0        0
16   B 2015-06-19    0        0
17   B 2015-06-20    0        0
18   B 2015-06-21    0        0
19   B 2015-06-22    0        0
20   B 2015-06-23    0        0
21   B 2015-06-24    0        0
22   B 2015-06-25    0        0
23   B 2015-06-26    0        0
24   B 2015-06-27    0        0
25   B 2015-06-28    0        0
26   B 2015-06-29    0        0
27   B 2015-06-30    0        0
28   B 2015-07-01    0        0
29   B 2015-07-02    0        0
30   B 2015-07-03    0        0
31   B 2015-07-04    0        0
32   B 2015-07-05    0        0
33   B 2015-07-06    0        0
34   B 2015-07-07    0        0
35   B 2015-07-08    0        0
36   B 2015-07-09    0        0
37   B 2015-07-10    0        0
38   B 2015-07-11    0        0
39   B 2015-07-12    0        0
40   B 2015-07-13    0        0
41   B 2015-07-14    0        0
42   B 2015-07-15    0        0
43   B 2015-07-16    0        0
44   B 2015-07-17    0        0
45   B 2015-07-18    0        0
46   B 2015-07-19    0        0
47   B 2015-07-20    0        0
48   B 2015-07-21    0        0
49   B 2015-07-22    0        0
50   B 2015-07-23    0        0
51   B 2015-07-24    0        0
52   B 2015-07-25    0        0
53   B 2015-07-26    0        0
54   B 2015-07-27    0        0
55   B 2015-07-28    0        0
56   B 2015-07-29    0        0
57   B 2015-07-30    0        0
58   B 2015-07-31    0        0
59   B 2015-08-01    0        0
60   B 2015-08-02    0        0
61   B 2015-08-03    0        0
62   B 2015-08-04    0        0
63   B 2015-08-05    0        0
64   B 2015-08-06    0        0
65   B 2015-08-07    1        1
66   C 2015-05-15    1        1
67   C 2015-05-16    0        1
68   C 2015-05-17    0        1
69   C 2015-05-18    0        1
70   C 2015-05-19    0        1
71   C 2015-05-20    0        1
72   C 2015-05-21    0        1
73   C 2015-05-22    0        1
74   C 2015-05-23    0        1
75   C 2015-05-24    0        1
76   C 2015-05-25    0        1
77   C 2015-05-26    0        1
78   C 2015-05-27    0        1
79   C 2015-05-28    0        1
80   C 2015-05-29    0        1
81   C 2015-05-30    0        1
82   C 2015-05-31    0        1
83   C 2015-06-01    0        1
84   C 2015-06-02    0        1
85   C 2015-06-03    0        1
86   C 2015-06-04    0        1
87   C 2015-06-05    0        1
88   C 2015-06-06    0        1
89   C 2015-06-07    0        1
90   C 2015-06-08    0        1
91   C 2015-06-09    0        1
92   C 2015-06-10    0        1
93   C 2015-06-11    0        1
94   C 2015-06-12    0        1
95   C 2015-06-13    0        1
96   C 2015-06-14    0        0
97   C 2015-06-15    0        0
98   C 2015-06-16    0        0
99   C 2015-06-17    0        0
100  C 2015-06-18    0        0
101  C 2015-06-19    0        0
102  C 2015-06-20    0        0
103  C 2015-06-21    0        0
104  C 2015-06-22    0        0
105  C 2015-06-23    0        0
106  C 2015-06-24    0        0
107  C 2015-06-25    0        0
108  C 2015-06-26    0        0
109  C 2015-06-27    0        0
110  C 2015-06-28    0        0
111  C 2015-06-29    0        0
112  C 2015-06-30    0        0
113  C 2015-07-01    0        0
114  C 2015-07-02    0        0
115  C 2015-07-03    0        0
116  C 2015-07-04    0        0
117  C 2015-07-05    0        0
118  C 2015-07-06    0        0
119  C 2015-07-07    0        0
120  C 2015-07-08    0        0
121  C 2015-07-09    0        0
122  C 2015-07-10    0        0
123  C 2015-07-11    0        0
124  C 2015-07-12    0        0
125  C 2015-07-13    0        0
126  C 2015-07-14    0        0
127  C 2015-07-15    0        0
128  C 2015-07-16    0        0
129  C 2015-07-17    0        0
130  C 2015-07-18    0        0
131  C 2015-07-19    0        0
132  C 2015-07-20    0        0
133  C 2015-07-21    0        0
134  C 2015-07-22    0        0
135  C 2015-07-23    0        0
136  C 2015-07-24    0        0
137  C 2015-07-25    0        0
138  C 2015-07-26    0        0
139  C 2015-07-27    0        0
140  C 2015-07-28    0        0
141  C 2015-07-29    0        0
142  C 2015-07-30    0        0
143  C 2015-07-31    0        0
144  C 2015-08-01    0        0
145  C 2015-08-02    0        0
146  C 2015-08-03    2        2
```

Unnecessary column `yes` will be deleted.

```
df2 = df2.drop(['yes'], axis=1 )
```

Output is merging with first dataframe `df`.

```
df2 = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['DATE', 'ID'], how='inner')
print df2

  ID       DATE  WIN  WIN1  NumOfDaysSinceLastWin  yes  rollsum
0  A 2015-06-07  Yes     1                      0    1        2
1  A 2015-06-07  Yes     1                      0    1        2
2  B 2015-08-07   No     0                      0  NaN        1
3  B 2015-08-07  Yes     1                      0    1        1
4  C 2015-05-15  Yes     1                      0    1        1
5  C 2015-05-30   No     0                     15  NaN        1
6  C 2015-07-30   No     0                     76  NaN        0
7  C 2015-08-03  Yes     1                     80    1        1
```

If values in column `count` are not `null`, they are added to column `count`.
Function `rolling_sum` is counted rows of original `df` with values `'YES'`, so it has to be subtracting. And this values (`1`) are in column `WIN1`.

```
df2.loc[df['count'].notnull() , 'WIN1'] = df2['count']
df2['NumOfWinsInThePast30days'] = df2['rollsum'] - df2['WIN1']
```

Delete unnecessary columns.

```
df2 = df2.drop(['yes','WIN1', 'rollsum', 'count'], axis=1 )
print df2
   ID       DATE  WIN  NumOfDaysSinceLastWin  NumOfWinsInThePast30days
0   A 2015-06-05  Yes                      0                         0
1   A 2015-06-05  Yes                      0                         0
2   A 2015-06-07  Yes                      2                         2
3   A 2015-06-07  Yes                      2                         2
4   A 2015-06-07  Yes                      2                         2
5   A 2015-06-08   No                      1                         5
6   B 2015-06-07   No                      0                         0
7   B 2015-06-07   No                      0                         0
8   B 2015-08-07  Yes                      0                         0
9   C 2015-05-15  Yes                      0                         0
10  C 2015-05-30   No                     15                         1
11  C 2015-07-30   No                     76                         0
12  C 2015-08-03  Yes                     80                         0
13  C 2015-08-03  Yes                     80                         0
```

And last all together:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

#original data
temp=u"""ID,DATE,WIN
A,2015/6/5,Yes
A,2015/6/7,Yes
A,2015/6/7,Yes
A,2015/6/8,No
B,2015/6/7,No
B,2015/8/7,Yes
C,2015/5/15,Yes
C,2015/5/30,No
C,2015/7/30,No
C,2015/8/03,Yes"""

#changed repeating data
temp2=u"""ID,DATE,WIN
A,2015/6/5,Yes
A,2015/6/5,Yes
A,2015/6/7,Yes
A,2015/6/7,Yes
A,2015/6/7,Yes
A,2015/6/8,No
B,2015/6/7,No
B,2015/6/7,No
B,2015/8/7,Yes
C,2015/5/15,Yes
C,2015/5/30,No
C,2015/7/30,No
C,2015/8/03,Yes
C,2015/8/03,Yes"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp2), parse_dates = [1])

df['WIN1'] = df['WIN'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else 0)
df['cumsum'] = df['WIN1'].cumsum()

#df['diffs'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'cumsum'])['DATE'].apply(lambda d: (d-d.shift()).fillna(0)) 

df['min'] = df.groupby(['ID','cumsum'])['DATE'].transform('min')
df['count'] = df.groupby(['cumsum'])['cumsum'].transform('count')

df1 = df[~df['WIN'].isin(['No'])]

df['date1'] = df1.groupby(['ID'])['DATE'].apply(lambda d: d.shift()) 
print df
df.loc[(df['count'] >= 1) & (df['date1'].isnull()), 'date1'] = df['min']
print df

#resolve repeating datetimes
df['count'] = df1.groupby(['ID', 'DATE', 'WIN1'])['WIN1'].transform('count')
df.loc[df['count'] == 1 , 'count'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['count'].notnull() , 'date2'] = df['date1']
print df

def repeat_value(grp):
    grp['date2'] = grp['date2'].min()
    return grp

df = df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE']).apply(repeat_value)
df.loc[df['date2'].notnull() , 'date1'] = df['date2']
print df

df['NumOfDaysSinceLastWin'] = (df['DATE'] - df['date1']).astype('timedelta64[D]')
df = df.drop(['cumsum','min','date1', 'date2'], axis=1 )
print df

#NumOfWinsInThePast30days
df['yes'] = df['WIN'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else np.nan)
df2 = df.set_index('DATE')
df2 = df2.drop(['NumOfDaysSinceLastWin','WIN', 'WIN1','count'], axis=1)

df2 = df2.groupby('ID').resample("D", how='count')
df2 = df2.reset_index()

df2['rollsum'] = df2.groupby('ID')['yes'].transform(pd.rolling_sum, window=30, min_periods=1)

#with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999, 'display.max_columns', 5):
    #print df2

df2 = df2.drop(['yes'], axis=1 )
df2 = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['DATE', 'ID'], how='inner')
print df2

df2.loc[df['count'].notnull() , 'WIN1'] = df2['count']
df2['NumOfWinsInThePast30days'] = df2['rollsum'] - df2['WIN1']

df2 = df2.drop(['yes','WIN1', 'rollsum', 'count'], axis=1 )
print df2
```